# Python on Linux says 'no such file or directory' even if it exists

Tags: python, linux, openpyxl, mount, smb

I'm getting the error `no such file or directory` from Python when I try to open a .xlsx file with openpyxl.

It's strange because:
All files (.py and .xlsx) are stored on my NAS.
The script reads several .xlsx files from different directories.
If I'm running the script on macOS (via SMB), everything works fine.
Python is in the correct directory and the file is definitely there. The name is 100% identical.
I can open the files manually, so they're not damaged.

But on my Linux VM running on my Server (via mount), the error occurs, but only at the 3rd file (the first two can be read).
They just differ in the fact that they were saved from gmail, but however, they don't look damaged etc.
The code for saving them:

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com" )
mail.login("mail@gmail.com","password")
mail.select('INBOX')
data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[1]
id_list = mail_ids[0].split()
if len(id_list)>=1:
    first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
    latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])

    for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id-1, -1):
        data = mail.fetch(str(i), '(RFC822)' )
        for response_part in data:
            arr = response_part[0]
            if isinstance(arr, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(str(arr[1],'utf-8'))
                email_subject = msg['subject']
                email_to = msg['to']

                counter = 1
                for part in msg.walk():
                    # multipart/* are just containers
                    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                        continue
                    # Applications should really sanitize the given filename so that an
                    # email message can't be used to overwrite important files
                    filename = part.get_filename()
                    if not filename:
                        ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(part.get_content_type())
                        if not ext:
                            # Use a generic bag-of-bits extension
                            ext = '.bin'
                        filename = f'part-{counter:03d}{ext}'
                    counter += 1
                    if ".xls" in filename:
                        with open(os.path.join(".", filename), 'wb') as fp:
                            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
```

The error occurs here:

```
if xyz == 1:
    Excel = "Gleichmäßigkeit_A+R.xlsx"
...
os.chdir("Klassen")
TKlasse1 = lw(Excel) # this file cant be opened, "lw" for openpyxl.load_workbook
TKlasse1 = TKlasse1["WL1"]
```

The full error output is:

```
paul@elementary:/mnt/paul/server/dhm$ python3 DHM.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DHM.py", line 347, in <module>
    TKlasse1 = lw(Excel)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/zipfile.py", line 1251, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Gleichmäßigkeit_A+R.xlsx'
```

Comment: Are you giving `openpyxl` a full path? Also, check that openpyxl is using a version of python that actually exists on your system. The "file not found" could be occurring at the hashbang level

Comment: Did you check any network and firewall issues in regards to the VM? Sometimes the network access is blocked due to configuration mistakes

Comment: Just to be sure: double check if your cwd is what you expect by adding `print(os.getcwd())`. Your cwd depends on how you execute your file.

Comment: @Durtal: yes. `print(os.getcwd())` and `print(os.listdir())`  are looking good.
@4lexKidd: The firewall on my server is currently completely turned off.
@barrycarter: how can I check it?
@Dan Getz: added the part that doesnt work to the original post

Comment: Show the full error output.

Comment: One possibility is that the filesystem's encoding is different from the one in your string. Comparing the string as returned from `os.listdir()` and the one you have hardcoded using `==` or another tool that tells you about invisible changes might be interesting.

Comment: @server_paul that would be better added to your question text in a code block. But you should confirm that the file is not open in another program (e.g. Excel) and that you are definitely in the working directory that you expect to be in. Otherwise you might have a filesystem text encoding problem, or there might be whitespace in the filename that you aren't aware of.

Comment: @shadowtalker added it. It's opened nowhere.

Comment: As an aside, it is extremely unlikely that the bytes you download from IMAP will be UTF-8. The proper solution is to use `message_from_bytes` (in 2022, almost certainly with `policy=email.policy.default` so that you get an `EmailMessage` back instead of the legacy `Message` from before Python 3.6).

Comment: @tripleee after changing msg = `email.message_from_strint(str(arr[1],'utf-8'))` to `msg = email.message_from_bytes(arr[1])` no files are saved.

Comment: The `, 'utf-8'` part belonged to the `str` which you got rid of. The proper syntax would look like `from email.policy import default as default_policy` ... `msg = message_from_bytes(arr[1], policy=default_policy)`

Comment: @server_paul as a debugging step, can you make a copy of this file that uses only ASCII characters in the name, and see if it works then?

Comment: No doubt there are additional bugs here. Probably review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name wasn't identical. It looked that way, but the name contained an "ä" which wasn't recognized correctly by Linux.